# angular 2 file upload 401 unauthorized (CORS)

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, cors, apache2

I am getting an error "401 Unauthorized" in Chrome and Firefox,
when uploading files with angular 2 CLI to an apache2-server.
The backend of the server is in PHP.
I've tried it with three different node modules, all behave the same.
I'm getting the error already on the OPTIONS-preflight,

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load (uploadurl) Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401".

This error only happens, if im requesting from another source (e.g. "localhost:4200").
But when executing this project on the apache server, the upload works fine.

So on localhost:
The difference is, all requests before uploading do have the cookie in request headers.
But not the upload-request.
here's an image:
[headers on the upload-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxLCh.png)

---

I've tried theese three Node Modules so far:

- ng2-file-upload
- angular2-http-file-upload
- ng2-uploader

"withCredentials" on the uploader itself (e.g. for the ng2-file-upload from Valor Software [ng-2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload)) is set to true.
I also tried already setting the header `X-Requested-With: 'XMLHttpRequest'`.
And i already tried setting an `Authorization: Basic`-header....Still the same issue.
When setting the `Cookie:`-header myself OnBeforeFileUpload, of course i get an error message

> "refused to set unsafe header Cookie"

would be cool, if someone knows how to fix this.
I just looked everywhere for an answer but nothing did help.

**EDIT:**
Theese headers are also set in the php backend:

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
```

still got the error.

Comment: take a simple step. Call you php server with a simple get request from a simple ajax cors call. That is a more simple approach to debug

Comment: all GET / POST - Requests before the upload work totally fine.
as i said, **all requests before uploading do have the cookie in request headers** and therefore those are all fine (Status 200 etc...)

Answer (score 0):

seems like server site error.

do you have below headers in your php files?

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: yea. i forgot to mention, that i set theese headers too. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: sadly, not yet. I edited the question, so the actual state is still as it is described in the question...